# WPF MVVM - Navigating and utilizing Dialogs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to MVVM and am struggling with identifying an eloquent approach to accomplish some common actions that are very straight forward in the absence of patterning with MVVM.  Before I go down the wrong road I thought I would post my challenges here to see if anyone has some mind-blowing and non-convoluted way to solve them.

For demonstration purposes, I’ll use a very simplistic model that consists of an Employee and Department entity along with corresponding views and models to represent them.  From my Create/Edit Employee View, the user needs to assign a department to an employee and is given the option to select from an existing department or Create a new one.

**First challenge:**

What is the best approach to present the user with a new view to create a department and then return that completed department back to my EmployeeViewModel and the view back to the EmployeeView so the user can continue on with Creating an employee?

I would like to simply call a CreateNewDepartment() method in my DepartmentViewModel from my EmployeeViewModel, but researched somewhere that having ViewModels talk to each other is taboo.  The benefit to this approach is that My EmployeeViewModel doesn’t need to know or care how the DepartmentViewModel get’s a new department, and I can re-use this approach from any view model where a department is required.

**Second challenge:**

What is the best way to control navigation?  Using the example above, how do I tell the view of the application to show a CreateDepartmentView when it is working within the CreateEmployeeView and needs to return to it once completed?

Comment: The downvote ferries will be coming out of the woods soon ... have you read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ? i doubt this is the place for this question ...

Comment: A short piece of source code should be more efficient than your long description to hope a piece of help. And if possible, provide a ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/ this is an awesome blog about WPF and MVVM